# Creating a QT Makefile: "dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore"

Tags: c++, qt, makefile

For educational purposes, I'm learning to create a QT makefile from scratch - without qmake.

Here is my Makefile:

```
SOURCES = calculator.cpp

INCPATH = -I. -I/usr/local/qt/5.9.1/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -I/usr/local/qt/5.9.1/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I/usr/local/qt/5.9.1/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I/usr/local/qt/5.9.1/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang -F/usr/local/qt/5.9.1/clang_64/lib

DEFINES = -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB

FRAMEWORK = -framework QtCore -framework QtGui -framework QtWidgets -framework OpenGL -framework DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework OpenGL -framework AGL

all:
    g++ -std=c++11 $(SOURCES) $(INCPATH) $(FRAMEWORK)
```

When I run `make`, there are no errors and an a.out file is generated successfully.

When I try to run that a.out file by typing `./a.out`, I get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore
  Referenced from: /Users/dougbeney/Desktop/Coding/Projects/cpp/Test/./a.out
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Any idea of what I'm missing? I tried checking out the generated qmake Makefile as a reference, but couldn't pinpoint what I needed.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out!

It was all in the LFLAGS.

Here is how I changed my Makefile to work:

```
SOURCES = calculator.cpp

INCPATH = -I. -I/usr/local/qt/5.9.1/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -I/usr/local/qt/5.9.1/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I/usr/local/qt/5.9.1/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I/usr/local/qt/5.9.1/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang -F/usr/local/qt/5.9.1/clang_64/lib

DEFINES = -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB

LFLAGS = -stdlib=libc++ -headerpad_max_install_names  -arch x86_64 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.10 -Wl,-rpath,@executable_path/Frameworks -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/qt/5.9.1/clang_64/lib

FRAMEWORK = -framework QtCore -framework QtGui -framework QtWidgets -framework OpenGL -framework DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework OpenGL -framework AGL

all:
    g++ -std=c++11 $(LFLAGS) $(SOURCES) $(INCPATH) $(FRAMEWORK)
```